How to schedule a background service to initiate every deployment without a controller action in IIS
I have built out a service to create an erxcel report which uploads to a cloud storage provider. I am creating a scheduled task to occur at midnight every night to run this service. My issue is I often am redeploying my application for updates and all and I am trying to figure out how to get this background task to run every time I redeploy. Can this be done automatically or do I need to create a controller action and manually remember to call it so the task starts?
My code is as follows:
public class ReviewSummaryBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    protected IReviewSummaryService _reviewSummaryService;
    
    public ReviewSummaryBackgroundService(IReviewSummaryService reviewSummaryService)
    {
        _reviewSummaryService = reviewSummaryService;
    }
    
    private static int SecondsUntilMidnight()
    {
        return (int)(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1.0) - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var countdown = SecondsUntilMidnight();

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (countdown-- <= 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    await OnTimerFiredAsync(stoppingToken);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // in future log exception
                }
                finally
                {
                    countdown = SecondsUntilMidnight();
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnTimerFiredAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _reviewSummaryService.ExportExcelReportAsync();
    }
}


You can't do what you ask with a scheduled service. First of all, timers simply aren't meant for day-long schedules. Second, Cloud providers (and even IIS) put idle applications to sleep to conserve resources. Your timer won't be able to fire. Cloud providers are aggressive about it to, as they use those resources to serve more apps using the same hardware. If you forced your service to stay awake (eg by pinging it) for an entire day, you'd have to pay for an entire day too. In a VM a better option would be to use a proper library like eg Hangfire, Quartz.net, Coravel.

In a service managed by the cloud host it's probably better to use the cloud's own scheduling features to make a call to your service that triggers the export.

We host our own vm internally. This is for my company so they have server and IIS is sitting on windows server 2019. So is there no solution and the one I accepted does not work?

Assuming you're registering the background service as follows, it will be started when your application starts:
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ReviewSummaryBackgroundService>();

If you want to ensure that the report doesn't get created on each local debugging attempt, but when deployed to your prod environment, you could take advantage of the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
public ReviewSummaryBackgroundService(IWebHostEnvironment env, IReviewSummaryService reviewSummaryService) 
{
    _Env = env;
    //...
}

private static TimeSpan TimeUntilMidnight()
{
    return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    var delay = _Env.IsProduction() ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeUntilMidnight();
    
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay, stoppingToken);
        
        try
        {
            await OnTimerFiredAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // in future log exception
        }

        delay = TimeUntilMidnight();
    }
}



Exactly what I was looking for and thanks for the improvements. I forgot about considering local deployments in dev.

You're welcome!

I use builder.Services.AddScoped<IReviewSummaryService, ReviewSummaryService>();

When I run the code though I do hit an issue that states "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'
Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
Innermost exception   System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot consume scoped service 'ARMS_API.Services.IReviewSummaryService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'." I always use scoped for my services but this is referring to singleton.

@Qiuzman this really isn't what you're looking for and won't work if, eg IIS or any other host puts the application to sleep due to inactivity. All cloud providers aggressively put idle services to sleep so they can serve active apps without extra hardware

I host my site on IIS.

@Qiuzman Didn't know you were hosting on IIS. But what Panagiotis Kanavos said is right. In order to get this to be executed periodically, I also had to set our Azure App Service to AlwaysOn in a similar scenario (which produces additional costs). I don't have any experience with IIS hosting, but I read about an AlwaysRunning setting in the Application Initialization module along with some other settings.

Regarding your issue with the scoped services: you could create a (short lived!) scope to resolve the service you need within the singleton background service, see the official docs.

I have set my iis app pool to always on, and my app to preload enabled. Hopefully this will fix the issue. Thoughts on this Panagiotis?
